# Why does 2nd ggplot not appear using knitr and grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, r-grid

I am trying to create a document using `knitr` that includes `ggplot2` plots modified using `grid`.

In the example below, there **should** be 2 plots both using the `diamonds` dataset included in `ggplot2`: the first one shows cut vs. color and the second shows cut vs. clarity. Instead, the later plot is repeated twice. The first plot is not generated in the `figure` directory at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<fig.cap = c('color', 'clarity')>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
theme_update(plot.margin = unit(c(1.5, 2, 1, 1), 'lines'))

# Create plot with color

p = ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,fill = color)) + geom_bar(position = 'fill') + annotate('text', label = as.character(table(diamonds$cut)), x = 1:5, y = Inf, vjust = -1)
gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == 'panel'] = 'off'
grid.draw(gt)

# Create plot with clarity

q = ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,fill = clarity)) + geom_bar(position = 'fill') + annotate('text', label = as.character(table(diamonds$cut)), x = 1:5, y = Inf, vjust = -1)
gs = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(q))
gs$layout$clip[gs$layout$name == 'panel'] = 'off'
grid.draw(gs)
@

\end{document}
```

Importantly, if I remove the following lines:

```
gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == 'panel'] = 'off'
grid.draw(gt)
```

from **both** figures, then they will both be generated correctly but the annotations will be cut off.

What is causing this issue, and more importantly, how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: you perhaps need a `grid.newpage()`

Comment: Adding `grid.newpage()` after the first plot did not change anything. Is that where you were thinking of placing it? After `grid.draw(gt)`?

Comment: Do you get two plots if you just use the ggplots (ie omitting all the grid stuffs)

Comment: Yes. Two different plots just as I expect to see.

Comment: hmmm, okay ... ah scratch that - i was using sweave rather than knitr

Comment: Ahh, now I cannot get it correct either (as you were saying)... now what did I do that changed????

Comment: hmm okay, seems to work after using  grid.newpage immediately before the second plot

Comment: Can you post an answer showing exactly where you're including the line?

Comment: okay Ceph, code below shows where i added the line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

adding code from comments

I added a `grid.newpage()` before the second plot to allow both to render. Also had to tweak the margins to get the annotations to show.

Sp your code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<< fig.cap = c('color', 'clarity')>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# Create plot with color

p = ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,fill = color)) + geom_bar(position = 'fill') + annotate('text', label = as.character(table(diamonds$cut)), x = 1:5, y = Inf, vjust = -1) + 
theme(plot.margin=unit( c(2,1,1,1), "lines") ) ### added

gt = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name == 'panel'] = 'off'
grid.draw(gt)

# Create plot with clarity

q = ggplot(diamonds,aes(cut,fill = clarity)) + geom_bar(position = 'fill') + annotate('text', label = as.character(table(diamonds$cut)), x = 1:5, y = Inf, vjust = -1) + 
theme(plot.margin=unit( c(2,1,1,1), "lines") ) ### added

gs = ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(q))
gs$layout$clip[gs$layout$name == 'panel'] = 'off'
grid.newpage() ## This is the extra line
grid.draw(gs)
@

\end{document}
```