# Using grid.raster to view png files in a Rmarkdown loop only plots one image

Tags: r, loops, r-markdown

I have a varying number of png files. Within Rmarkdown, I am attempting to create a new heading and display the png file.

I have created a minimal example below.

I use looping construct shown below often in various other similar plotting cases, however with grid.raster I only get the last plot.

Looking for help to resolve this.

````
---
title: "Buggy Looping with grid.raster"
author: "Author"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
png("test1.png") ; heatmap(as.matrix(iris[,-5])); dev.off()
png("test2.png") ; heatmap(as.matrix(mtcars))   ; dev.off()
pltNames <- list.files(pattern = "^test.+\\.png$")
```

```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in seq_len(length(pltNames))){
  cat('\n')  
  cat("# This is a heading for ", pltNames[i], "\n") 
  cat('\n')  
  grid::grid.raster(png::readPNG(pltNames[i]))
  cat('\n') 
}
```
````

Comment: you may need a [`grid::grid.newpage()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597687/why-does-2nd-ggplot-not-appear-using-knitr-and-grid/34598187#34598187)

Comment: Many thanks user20650!  Adding grid::grid.newpage() first fixes the problem!

Comment: you're welcome - I'll mark it as a duplicate as I think they are more or less the same.